# PHP Form Re-Populate Fail

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, populate

Im Repopulating a form via `PHP Post` Commands.
It all works fine, the data is send and received perfectly, but whenever I check if `$_POST[Ticket] == 2` it counts as `true` even if echo `$_POST[Ticket]` echoes a 1 or anything but a 2...

heres my code:

```
echo '<select title="Ticket" name="Ticket" required>';
echo '<option disabled selected value>Art des Tickets</option>';
echo '<option value="1"';
if ($_POST['Ticket'] == "1") echo 'selected="selected"';
echo '>Gamer</option><option value="2"';
if ($_POST['Ticket'] == "2") echo 'selected="selected"';
echo '>Zuschauer</option></select>';

if ($_POST[Ticket] == 2)
{
    echo '<div class="FormError">Als Zuschauer kannst du leider nur beim Auf- oder Abbau helfen, nicht jedoch bei beidem, bitte ändere deine Auswahl.</div>';
}
```

I just realized that this part does not work but the part above began to work after adding the improvements mentioned below...

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 2)
        {
            echo '<div class="FormError">Als Zuschauer kannst du leider nur beim Auf- oder Abbau helfen, nicht jedoch bei beidem, bitte ändere deine Auswahl.</div>';
        }

        if ($AHelfer < $Veranstaltung->AHelfer or $BHelfer < $Veranstaltung->BHelfer)
        {
            echo '<select ';
            if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 2) echo 'class="FormError"';
            echo ' title="Hilfe" name="Hilfe" required>';
            echo '<option disabled selected value>Ich helfe...</option>';
            if ($AHelfer < $Veranstaltung->AHelfer)
            {
                echo '<option value="1"';
                if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 1) {echo 'selected="selected"'; }
                echo '>...beim Aufbau (5€ Rabatt)</option>';
            }
            if ($BHelfer < $Veranstaltung->BHelfer)
            {
                echo '<option value="2"';
                if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 2) {echo 'selected="selected"'; }
                echo '>...beim Abbau (5€ Rabatt)</option>';
            }
            if ($AHelfer < $Veranstaltung->AHelfer && $BHelfer < $Veranstaltung->BHelfer)
            {
                echo '<option value="3"';
                if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 3) {echo 'selected="selected"'; }
                echo '>...beim Auf- und Abbau (10€ Rabatt)</option>';
            }
            echo '<option value="4"';
            if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 4) {echo 'selected="selected"'; }
            echo '>...Nicht (Kein Rabatt)</option>';
            echo '</select>';
        }
        echo $_POST[Hilfe];
```

Comment: add `'` quotes around Ticket in the condition. `if ($_POST['Ticket'] == 2`...

Comment: no change... btw i never had to use quotes... always worked without...

Comment: You should. Without that PHP parse it as a constant. If no `Ticket` constant exists, the value of it will be `Ticket`. So it will be always true. Update your code with your fixed code please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I littlebit rewrote your code to be much readable. It works for me. You need to add single or double quotes around the `Ticket` in condition:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select title="Ticket" name="Ticket" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Art des Tickets</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 1) {echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Gamer</option> 
        <option value="2" <?php if (!empty($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 2) {echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Zuschauer</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["Ticket"] == 2) {
    ?>
    <div class="FormError">Als Zuschauer kannst du leider nur beim Auf- oder Abbau helfen, nicht jedoch bei beidem, bitte ändere deine Auswahl.</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```